# Continuous VBA commands

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue making a continuous macro work. I have a filter set on a 'dashboard' sheet, which pulls information from a different sheets. I would like the macro to auto run, continuously updating the filter when ever the cells in the source sheet update. My code is below: what needs amending?
thanks so much. (`S&P500` is source sheet. Dashboard is sheet with the Macro on)

```
    Sub Yes ()
    '
    ' Yes Macro
    '
    'Private Sub S&P500Stocks_Activate()
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$499").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criterial:="Yes", _
             Operator:=xlAnd
    'Private Sub S&P500Stocks_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$499").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criterial:="Yes", _
             Operator:=xlAnd
    End Sub
```

Help would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

First make sure Sub *Yes()* is in a Standard Module rather than on a worksheet.
 Second change `ActiveSheet` to `Sheets("S&P500")`
Third make Sub *Yes()* Public

Then to go the worksheet code area for `Sheets("S&P500")` and install this event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.EnableEvents = False
      Call Yes
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am however a bit of a novice.

Comment: How do I make sure something is a standard module rather than a worksheet? How do I make Yes public? thanks so much!!

Comment: I have got all the above auto working now. If I have set another sheet up with a macro that I want to run continuously using the same worksheets but different info within them. If I use the code:         Private Sub         Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
           Application.EnableEvents = False
              Call Yes
           Application.EnableEvents = True
        End Sub

Comment: Private Sub         Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
           Application.EnableEvents = False
              Call Yes
           Application.EnableEvents = True                                          Private Sub         Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
           Application.EnableEvents = False
              Call Dboard 2
           Application.EnableEvents = True                                                   End Sub

Comment: For some reason it is showing an error....When trying to have two commands like this in the worksheet event macro....